# Spring boot - JPA Hibernate - Mysql UTF8 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, utf-8, spring-data-jpa

MySql 5.7 on my windows machine
Spring boot 1.4.0 RELEASE
mysql jdbc driver is 5.1.39

I have a table, has a few VARCHAR columns, and they all set to VARCHAR(100).
The encoding is set to:`ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` for the table.

I have verified that if I used MYSql Workbench I can insert 100 non English characters (such as Chinese).

Now to my java code, the field I am going to insert is an Spanish string, the `getBytes().length`  returns 115 so it is 115 bytes.

Since the field in DB is 100 characters, I would assume that inserting a 115 bytes string shouldn't be a problem.  But it is my problem, I got this:

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'addr1' at row 1`

I have tried to add `useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf-8&characterEncoding=utf-8` to the URL, tried to add connectionProperty
`useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;` to my application.yaml etc, no luck

then I changed `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `@Configuration` and add this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(databaseDriverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
    ds.setUsername(databaseUsername);
    ds.setPassword(databasePassword);
    ds.setConnectionProperties("useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;");
    ds.setInitSQL("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';");

    return ds;

}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.xxx.entity");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "utf8mb4");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8mb4");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
    factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
    factory.setDataSource(datasource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Still have the same thing!

I spent 2 days on it now... :-( I think must be a simple mistake I have made, but what is the mistake?

Thanks

Edit:  Tried to just save the record by calling the repository interface and it worked!  So the problem is calling entitymanager.merge().  Is there any properties I need to set for entity manager to handle UTF8?

Edit:  I added more debug code, now the problem seems nothing to do with JPA or hibernate...

The string I am getting is from a SOAP call to magento SOAP API.  Here is my code now:

```
    String s = "其次受影响较大的是金融体系，过去那么多年金融体系受益于低利率、信贷宽松、影子银行大扩张等，金融企业疯狂的扩张资产负债表，一个个都赚的钵满盆满（看看过去数年金融企业的疯狂高利润和增速，从业人员增速和工";
    salesOrderModel.setAddr1(s);

    try {
        System.out.println(s + ", " + "[" + s.length() + "][" + s.getBytes("UTF-8").length + "]");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And with above code, the `entitymanager.merge()` works no problem, and data is inserted into the database, and this is the system output:

```
其次受影响较大的是金融体系，过去那么多年金融体系受益于低利率、信贷宽松、影子银行大扩张等，金融企业疯狂的扩张资产负债表，一个个都赚的钵满盆满（看看过去数年金融企业的疯狂高利润和增速，从业人员增速和工, [99][297]
```

Now if I comment out B1 and B2, and uncomment A1 and A2:

```
salesOrderModel.setAddr1(address.getStreet());
    String s = address.getStreet();


    try {
        System.out.println(s + ", " + "[" + s.length() + "][" + s.getBytes("UTF-8").length + "]");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I received the exception mentioned at the beginning of the post, and this is the system output:

```
Plaça Pla de L'Estany, 5, Edificio Vueling Airlines S.A., [113][115]
```

The  string length is 113。

If I do this:

```
String s = "Plaça Pla de L'Estany, 5, Edificio Vueling Airlines S.A.";
```

And the output is:

```
Plaça Pla de L'Estany, 5, Edificio Vueling Airlines S.A., [56][57]
```

Now the string length is 56 (vs 113).  Why?

Comment: so... by using mySqlworkbench you can add the record (chinese if i'm not wrong) while using spring and spring boot you can't (always chinese). Right? If it's so... I guess there is come encoding from java to DB layer and your chinese sentence is encoded (maybe UTF-8) and it becomes longer than 100 character. Try to log the full SQL statement (params too)

Comment: @TheMW what does `Charset.defaultCharset()` says on the machine where you run this? `getBytes().length` will show the output in bytes for the default charset. For example `"MaÑÚÜana".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE).length` will show 16 bytes...

Comment: @Angelo Immediata correct, I can do it in mysqlworkbench, but not in java, however in java I was trying to insert the Spanish character which is also in UTF8 and the length in byte is 115 according to getBytes().length

Comment: @Eugene `Charset.defaultCharset()` returns UTF_8 and displayname of it is `UTF-8`

Comment: OK, per this link:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

Added `spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties` still the same problem.

Then tried Spring boot 1.3.3, still the same thing (of course in 1.3.3 I was using `spring.datasource.connection-properties`.

Comment: Tried to call the repository interface directly and it worked.  So the problem is with entitymanager.merge().  any special settings for entity manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally finally I found the problem, my stupid mistake!

The string indeed is too long for the field.  Basically the string contains two lines of `Plaça Pla de L'Estany, 5, Edificio Vueling Airlines S.A.` and I did not notice it until now.

My bad!